# jQuery onClick tr

Tags: jquery

Есть таблица, в которой строки содержат класс "selectable"

```
<tr class="selectable">
 <td></td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
```

Почему этот обработчик срабатывает при нажатии на строки содержащие класс

```
$(document).on('click', '.selectable', function(){
 alert('123');
});
```

А этот не срабатывает?

```
$('.selectable').on('click', function(){
 alert('123');
});
```

Comment: Скорее всего, эти элементы `.selectable` появляются на странице позже добавления обработчика события `$('.selectable').on('click'`. Если они не добавляются динамически, то нужно обернуть код в обработчик события document.ready. Если динамически, то либо обработчик добавлять после появления элементов, либо использовать делегирование (первый вариант).

Comment: Строки действительно добавляются динамически. Спасибо за ответ @Regent

Answer (score 0):

Если честно, не ковырялся,  не искал причины такого поведения, но чисто случайно, методом тыка, как-то давно выяснил, что без `<table>`  теги `<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>` `JS-ом` или `JQ` не определяюся

```js
$('.selectable').on('click', function() {
  alert('123');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="selectable">
    <td>tttttttttt</td>
    <td>tttttttttttt</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```